# string.split("_(B")

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Basically this line of code does not work and I'm not quite sure as to why:

```
    String[] stringHolder = string.split("_(B");
```

I get this error: Unclosed group near index 3

This line of code works however:

```
    String[] stringHolder = string.split("_B");
```

So this leads me to believe that it's caused by the "(". Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `(` is a special character in regex, you need to escape it with a `\`. And since `\` needs to be escaped inside a string literal, you add two:

```
String[] stringHolder = string.split("_\\(B");
```

More info: [Use Round Brackets for Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 5):

The `split()` method takes a regular expression, not a string literal. So you need to escape the opening bracket/parenthesis:

```
String[] stringHolder = string.split("_\\(B");
```

Brackets are special characters in regular expressions, used for groups.

Comment: A bit strange: "not a string", but +1

Answer (score 1):

Some special characters need to be escaped maybe putting `"_\\(B"` might work.